# Java, Обработка HTTP запросов, приходящих на Android

Tags: java, android, http

Пишу приложение для `Android`, нужно принять и обработать `http` запрос.

Скачала с `apache.org` пакеты `.jar` положила в папку `libs` проекта, `IDE` видит библиотеки apache но я не знаю с какой стороны к ним подступиться, я разобралась как отправлять запросы из приложения, а вот как в этом же приложении принимать запросы никак не могу догадаться, и ведь тут наверно надо запускать много потоков что бы они слушали соединения, вдруг будет сразу несколько запросов.

Подозреваю что из всех пакетов мне нужен `org.apache.http`, но в папке несколько файлов:

```
commons-codec-1.9.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar
fluent-hc-4.5.1.jar
httpclient-4.5.1.jar
httpclient-cache-4.5.1.jar
httpclient-win-4.5.1.jar
httpcore-4.4.3.jar
httpmime-4.5.1.jar
jna-4.1.0.jar
jna-platform-4.1.0.jar
```

Если подключить их все, возникает конфликт.
Какой из этих файлов нужен что бы обрабатывать `http` запрос и как это реализовать? Или сколько потоков нужно сразу запускать?

Comment: Пока не знаю что это но встретила на английском stack'e что-то про tomcat попробую покопать в эту сторону

Comment: А к какому серверу вы планируете подключиться, и данные какого вида получить?

Comment: @Werder, наоборот, я мне нужно что бы я принимала запросы как web сервер. Что бы к приложению можно было подключиться из браузера

Comment: Применять смартфон в качестве сервера - достаточно непростая задача ) Действительно стоит задача такой реализации?

Comment: Да, нужно сделать web мордочку для приложения

Comment: @Nastya на смартфоне и сервер и приложение и клиент? что-то намудрённое и непонятное.. сделать на андроиде сервер - это извращение. но если и сделать это - то мордочка в браузере будет обращаться с по адресу localhost...

Comment: @Вадим Нее, на телефоне только приложение в котором сервер, а клиент (Браузер) на компьютере.

Comment: @Nastya, Поднять сервер на смартфоне будет сложновато, поэтому посоветовал бы вам сделать сервис на каком нибудь сервере, а если нужно чтобы в телефоне была актуальная информация - сделать сервис, который будет запрашивать изменения на сервере, и если надо - подкачивать актуальную информацию

Comment: Дело в том, что актуальная информация как раз на телефоне. Свой web сервер не подразумевает наличия php, нужно только разобрать запрос и в зависимости от получаемых данных выполнить действия на телефоне.

Comment: @Nastya Браузер подразумевает наличие сервера(как основной вариант), сервер на андроиде на любом языке(java, php) вещь экзотическая и извращенческая. помимо того, IP у смартфона не постоянный, поэтому подключаться к нему будет проблемотично. если есть необходимость передать информацию с анодроида на клиента - правильный вариант : организовать сервер на компе, аднроид можно подключить к этому серверу с помощью websocket, а уж подключить браузер к этому серверу -не проблема. и можно в реальном времени получать инфу с андроида в браузере

Comment: У меня будет постоянный, телефон будет использоваться через wi-fi я его по маку привяжу на DHCP сервере, и выдам свой домен через DNS Static если 10.1.1.15 устану вводить :)

Comment: @Nastya т.е. это для локальной сети? тогда какие проблемы с организацией сервера на компе? тот же томкат,

Comment: Не хочется связываться с репликацией, поэтому на телефоне было бы проще. Чем проще структура тем она надёжнее. Меньше узлов выше отказоустойчивость.

Comment: зачем репликация? на телефоне сервер - намного сложнее. тут уже был вопрос по аналогичной проблеме, но автор его удалил, там я ссылку давал, кто-то что-то подобное сделал - но чисто из мазахизма..

Comment: сервер на андроиде не означает повышение помехоустойчивости. простой сервер даже на windows(томкат запущенный как сервис) будет намного надежнее.

Comment: Вся актуальная информация на телефоне, что бы сервер выступал в качестве фронтенда нужно организовать репликацию изменений состояний на него, что бы и на нём была актуальная информация. А это усложняет структуру. Если упадёт сервис на телефоне, толку от tomcata на win будет не больше чем от лука без стрел.

Comment: я аналогичную структуру делал - трекер, показывать координаны телефона на карте в браузере, работало великолепно.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29664/discussion-between--and-nastya).

Comment: @pavlofff ты не мог бы принять участие?

Answer (score 2):

На английском SO рекомендуют этот проект https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd

Написал небольшой проект с использованием этой библиотеки, весь проект можно посмотреть тут: https://github.com/ASEgorov/HttpServerExample

Основные моменты:

1. Создается новый класс как наследник от `NanoHTTPD`

   ```
   public class Server extends NanoHTTPD {
       private static final String LOG_TAG = "MyServer";
       private String parameter;

       public Server(int port) throws IOException {
           super(port);
           start();
           Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Server started");
       }

       @Override
       public Response serve(IHTTPSession session) {
           Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Receive query");
           String msg = "<html><body><h1>Hello server</h1>\n";
           msg += "<p>Hello, " + parameter + "!</p>";
           return new Response( msg + "</body></html>\n" );
       }

       public void setParameter(String parameter) {
           this.parameter = parameter;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Инициализируете этот сервер, например при старте Activity:

   ```
   try {
       mServer = new Server(8080);
   } catch (IOException e) {
       Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Can't start server", e);
   }
   ```
3. Я передавал данные в этот сервер по кнопке (чтобы проверить что ответ от сервера изменяется):

   ```
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       TextView param = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.someData);
       mServer.setParameter(param.getText().toString());
   }
   ```

Для того чтобы это все работало нужно добавить в Gradle соответствующую библиотеку `compile 'com.nanohttpd:nanohttpd:2.1.1'` и разрешение в манифест `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`